# The syntax of CSS class selectors, id selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors, w3c

In the latest version of [Selectors Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/):

> The class selector is given as a full stop (. U+002E) immediately followed by an identifier.
>
> An ID selector consists of a “number sign” (U+0023, #) immediately followed by the ID value, which must be a CSS [identifier](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier).

In the identifier link above:

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); **cannot start with** a digit, **two hyphens**, or a hyphen followed by a digit.

However, in that same spec, the [Grammar](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#grammar) part:

> `<class-selector> = '.' <ident-token>`
>
> `<id-selector> = <hash-token>`

As you can see from the token links above, the syntax diagram explicitly specifies that a CSS identifer may begin with **two hyphens**, and the grammar of an ID selector contradicts with the grammar of a hash-token.

Which definitions should I follow?

UPDATE:

I missed a line in the bottom of the [Grammar](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#grammar) section:

> In <id-selector>, the <hash-token>’s value must be an [identifier](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-syntax-3/#identifier).

Comment: css-variables makes this even more confusing. See my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30819462/can-css-identifiers-begin-with-two-hyphens).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can CSS identifiers begin with two hyphens?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30819462/1529630)

Answer (score 1):

The `hash-token` diagram must be wrong, as you quoted it:

> element names, classes, and IDs in selectors (...) cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit

It is very explicit

Comment: Clearly, between these definitions of an ID selector, only one of them is correct, just not sure which one. I think it's also quite possible that the editors forgot to update some of the definitions (esp. links), considering it's still a working draft.

Comment: Definitely only one is correct, but as one of them is explicit while the other one is a generalization, I think the one I quoted is the good one

Comment: It turns out, (see my update) the diagram is fine, since it's not used to describe the grammar of an id selector, but a hash. And fwiw, according to the new grammar of a CSS identifier, using two hyphens at the beginning is allowed now.

Comment: The quote is from CSS21. CSS Syntax 3 changed that.