# CSS classes prefixed with '--' are ignored in Safari

Tags: css, safari

In my own personal style, I liked adding small helper CSS classes with a command-line-argument-like syntax, such as

```
<div class="button --small --red"></div>
```

But I realized today that any class prefixed with `--` is ignored in Safari and iOS, however seems to work as expected in Firefox and Chrome. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Related: [Can CSS identifiers begin with two hyphens?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30819462/can-css-identifiers-begin-with-two-hyphens) - in short, Firefox allows it because css-variables allows it, and Chrome allows it either because Chrome once had a css-variables implementation that has since been scrapped, or because Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [CSS 2.1 it is invalid grammar](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html) for an identifier and the rules are the same in the lastest CSS3 ([see the "railroad tracks"](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#token-diagrams)) recommendation. Here are the relevant rules for CSS 2.1:

```
ident       -?{nmstart}{nmchar}*
nmstart     [_a-z]|{nonascii}|{escape}
nmchar      [_a-z0-9-]|{nonascii}|{escape}
```

An identifier can start with an optional `-` (0x2d); the second character is from the restricted `nmstart` and cannot be a `-` or an ASCII digit.

Browsers that accept `--foo` as an identifier are using "more relaxed" rules (classify as desired).

---

If really wanting to get technical/fancy/confusing, any Unicode character with a CP higher than 0x240 can be used as the second character as it conforms to `{nonascii}` - this includes a wide range of [hyphen/minus-like characters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pd/list.htm). YMMV on browser interoperability and sustainability:

```
<div class="button ––small —red"></div>
```

Please don't do this: the first is two EN DASH (0x2013) characters, the latter is a single EM DASH (0x2014) character. Good luck debugging selectors/code with either.